# Selecting specific nodes and changing style (for those nodes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Is it possible to select specific nodes and color them green?

I was thinking of using another for loop, but it doesn't seem like I can define more than 1 style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=MidnightBlue!25,minimum size=2.0em}][lightstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=Green!25,minimum size=2.0em}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{5 + 5*\x - \y}
       \node [darkstyle]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\label};} 

  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (\x\y)--(\x\yi) (\y\x)--(\yi\x) ;

  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \for each \y in {0, 4}
        \node [lightstyle]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Once a node is drawn, it is drawn. You can't change that later.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But can I define lightstyle like that? Or just 2 different styles?

Comment: @AlanH: Qrrbrbirlbel is right, but rather than try to draw again things you can select some nodes in a list then test if the name is contained in the list: if yes draw the node with another style. More or less something like: `\foreach \list in {22,33,44}{       \ifnum\x\y=\list \node [thick, darkstyle, fill=green!70!blue,minimum size=2.5em]  (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};\fi}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `.try` a style that has a name combined from the *x* and the *y* value of the current node. (Without the `.try` handler you’d need define every possible style combination.)

Sadly, `\tikzset` cannot used inside a `\foreach` loop as this executes its body only locally.
I thought about defining global PGF keys but I think the `etoolbox` solution is easier to adapt.

The `\foreach` loops “collect” all `\tikzset` which we later execute with `\myTikZsets`.

### Code 1

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=2.0em},
    darkstyle/.style={fill=MidnightBlue!25},
    lightstyle/.style={fill=Green!25},
    redstyle/.style={fill=red!25},
    style for 1-3/.style={redstyle},
    style for 3-3/.style={redstyle},
]
\foreach \x in {0,...,4} {
    \foreach \y in {0,4} {
        \xappto\myTikZsets{\noexpand\tikzset{style for \x-\y/.style=lightstyle}}
    }
}
\myTikZsets % use the stored \tikzset calls
\renewcommand*{\myTikZsets}{}% and empty it again (for later use)
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{5 + 5*\x - \y}
       \node [darkstyle, style for \x-\y/.try]  (n-\x-\y) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\label};} 
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (n-\x-\y)--(n-\x-\yi) (n-\y-\x)--(n-\yi-\x) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code 2

With the example you have given this can also be made with plain TeX `\ifnum`s.

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=2.0em},
    darkstyle/.style={fill=MidnightBlue!25},
    lightstyle/.style={fill=Green!25},
]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{5 + 5*\x - \y}
       \ifnum\y=0
         \tikzset{darkstyle/.style={lightstyle}}
       \fi
       \ifnum\y=4
         \tikzset{darkstyle/.style={lightstyle}}
       \fi
       \node [darkstyle]  (n-\x-\y) at (1.5*\x,-1.5*\y) {\label};} 
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
      \draw (n-\x-\y)--(n-\x-\yi) (n-\y-\x)--(n-\yi-\x) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @AlanH But wait, there's more. (See updated answer.)